# Unity ScriptableObjects and String Interpolation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I am sure its possible, but I haven't figured out how. How would I go about using string interpolation for scriptableObjects? Some basic code I have for it:

```cs
    public class ScriptableCardBase : ScriptableObject
    {
      public string cardDes;
    }
        
     public class CardUI : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public List<ScriptableCardBase> card = new List<ScriptableCardBase>();
        
        public Text desText;
        
        public void DisplayCard(int i)
        {
         desText.text = card[i].cardDes;
        }
    }
```

For my cards, I just want to be able to display the damage of the card, or number of effects, etc. Here is a screenshot of what the SO Card looks like and where I try to input the string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[CardSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILuju.png)

I guess a long questions short is, can I use string interpolation with scriptable objects?

Comment: Nothing out of the box, no. The difficult bit of that system, which is turning expressions into values, is handled at compile time, so you'd have to reimplement what the C# compiler does. Although, if you limit the valid expressions to a specific subset, for example fields on the object, you can probably get away with a regex.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking for here. You can do string interpolation in the `CardUI` class, so what do you mean when you're asking if you can do string interpolation "for scriptable objects?" You could do something like `desText.text = $"This card does {card[i].damage} damage with a {card[i].effect} effect."`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to convert your string to its Formattable version.

You can do it via reflection or some sort of IL you want. Some start could be:

```
public static string ParseFromFormattable(this string str, object context) {
    // Define a random char that is unlikely to appear on normal text.
    const char weirdChar = '°'; // This will prepend the interpolation parameters

    var outputStr = "";

    // Split all the parts and iterate through them, using reflection to get the value from values inside '{}'
    foreach (var part in GetStringParts()) {
        if (part[0] == weirdChar) { outputStr += context.GetType().GetField(part.Substring(1)).GetValue(context).ToString(); }
        else { outputStr += part; }
    }
    return "";


    List<string> GetStringParts() {
        var strParts = new List<string>();
        var currentPart = "";
        var writingParam = false;

        foreach (var c in str) {
            if (c == '{') {
                if (currentPart != "") { strParts.Add(currentPart); }
                currentPart = "";
                writingParam = true;
            }
            else if (writingParam && c == '}') {
                strParts.Add(weirdChar + currentPart);
                currentPart = "";
                writingParam = false;
            }
            else { currentPart += c; }
        }
        strParts.Add(currentPart); // Don't forget to add the last string
        return strParts;
    }
}
```

***Note this is a very basic  version that doesn't support complex interpolation parameters.. Only parameters that are field members of the class that is passed as 'context' will be supported.***

You can expand the reflection parts to support propeties, methods, and references if you want.. or even direct code (math operations, etc).
I would highly recommend just using some IL instead, though.